# Authenticate client via Azure Active Directory to connect to ApiApp

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory

I secured my Azure API App with Azure Active Directory.

How to authenticate my C# .NET client so I can call the Api? I can't find any tutorials on this!

Comment: which sort of client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's lots of comprehensive documentation and samples in  https://aka.ms/aaddev, you should spend some time poking around there. My response below all comes from those samples, specifically this one:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop

First off, you'll need to register you client app in Azure Active Directory by following these steps :

> 1. Sign in to the Azure management portal.
> 2. Click on Active Directory in the left hand nav.
> 3. Click the directory tenant where you wish to register the sample application.
> 4. Click the Applications tab.
> 5. In the drawer, click Add.
> 6. Click "Add an application my organization is developing".
> 7. Enter a friendly name for the application, i.e. "YourClientApp", select "Native Client Application", and click next.
> 8. Enter a Redirect URI, i.e. "https://yourClientsRedirectUri/". Click finish.
> 9. Click the Configure tab of the application.
> 10. Find the Client ID value and copy it aside, you will need this later when configuring your application.
> 11. In "Permissions to Other Applications", click "Add Application." Select "Other" in the "Show" dropdown, and click the upper check mark. Locate & click on "YourApi", and click the bottom check mark to add the application. Select "Access YourApi" from the "Delegated Permissions" drop down, and save the configuration.

Then, for a C# .NET client, you'll need to use the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for .Net and do something along the lines of:

```
var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
var resource = "https://yourApisUri/";
var redirectUri = "https://yourClientsRedirectUri/";

var tenant = "yourAzureActiveDirectory.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "yourClientsAzureADClientId";

var ctx = new AuthenticationContext(authority + tenant);

var t = ctx.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri));

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + t.AccessToken);

    var url = "https://yourapi.com/yourmethod";
    await result = client.GetAsync(url);

    // Do whatever you want
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** The code above is just a starting point, you should make sure you read and follow all the best practices such as ensuring you pass a TokenCache to the AuthenticationContext constructor and making sure you call AcquireToken every time you need a token and not caching the token yourself.